# tomcat8 ajp: servlet has no session content

Tags: servlets, tomcat8, ajp

Status: tomcat8, redirect from apache2 via ajp

Apache2 VirtualHost directive contains:

```
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/SecureMain/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/SecureMain/
```

Tomcat8 server.xml contains:

```
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

When servlet runs, header contains JSESSIONID, but getAttribute returns null.

When running the same servlet directly via tomcat8 port 8080, session content is availalble.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Then please, include your apache2 HTTP configuration in the question.

Comment: could it be a cookie problem, in that the IP address of the http request is changed somehow ?

Comment: It's most likely to be about session persistence across the set-up, that's why apache2 configuration is relevant

Comment: Where in the apache2 configuration ? Which part could I show here ?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the use of `StickySession` attribute on `ProxyPass` should do. [This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/344884/load-balancing-and-clustering-using-mod-proxy-ajp-on-apache-http-server-2-2-21-a) on ServerFault gives an idea about how to configure ajp.

`stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid`

Comment: I tried:  `ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/SecureMain/ stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid` but that yields: "unknown Worker parameter"